# Access Violation - javacdromwrapper.dll

Tags: java, access-violation

I'm currently trying to redirect an ISO over JViewer IPMI (v1) on a server with an Intel motherboard: ***DBS1200SPL***

JViewer, which is essentially KVM Remote Console Utility running on v1.34 that uses javaws.exe (.jnlp) extension, works absolutely fine until I try to do any device redirects (ISO, CDROM, USB Key, Floppy) and will instantly crash and generate a hs_err log. The log can be found here: https://hastebin.com/vujuyucozo.yaml

The only information that I can salvage, from a POV of barely any experience in debugging Java is the following:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000001000122f, pid=11332, tid=0x0000000000003b4c
```

And

```
# C  [javacdromwrapper.dll+0x122f]
```

Googling around for the javacdromwrapper.dll doesn't return much information at all. Most of the information you can find is related to the EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION which suggests to do various things. Below is the things I have tried:

> 1. Tried JRE versions 5 > 8 on 3 different machines. 2 newly installed Desktops and 1 seperate server. Same result on each of them.
> 2. Disabled UAC in Windows
> 3. Running javaws.exe as an Administrator in the compatibility tab in properties
> 4. Run javaws.exe with the arguments in the log file + -Xmx arguments for RAM increase in-case it was a resource issue on CMD run as admin
> 5. Increased the paging size in Configure Java
> 6. Checked the javaws.policy file inside "**C:\Program Files\Java\jre_\lib\security\javaws.policy**" to ensure **permission java.security.AllPermission;** is set
> 7. Used JDK binaries instead versions 5 > 8 with the same problem on this side.

I should also add that I'm using IPMI on a bare metal server through OVH control panel. I've tried to contact their support who just redirected me to online forums with fixes that have no relation to this issue, hence why I have come here for some extra hands. I have requested for them to update the BMC firmware if they can.

None of this as worked and now I've hit a dead end and a mental block. Appreciate any help, if any.

Comment: I have the same issue, but using ServerBoard S5520HC

Comment: @dodancs, you should have a look to my answer :)

Comment: I have the same issue with Check Point firewall appliances. Windows Server 2019, Adoptium `JRE version: OpenJDK Runtime Environment (8.0_362-b09)` `Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (25.362-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)`

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue several times and I have finally figured out that this is related to Java 64 bits on Windows 10+.

We have been finally able to connect virtual media using [Java 32 bits](https://developers.redhat.com/content-gateway/file/java-1.8.0-openjdk-jre-1.8.0.322-2.b06.dev.redhat.windows.x86.zip) !

Comment: Did you also try Java 32 bit on Windows? Were you successful?

Comment: It's with Java 32 bits on Windows we have have been successful.